# Is there a way to show only the highest value of a category for each country on a table that has an aggregate function

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

This is the original query I created:

```
Select DISTINCT
  COUNTRY, 
  CategoryName, 
  SUM(od.unitprice * od.Quantity) 
From Categories c 
Join Products p on c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID  
Join [Order Details] od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
Join Orders o on od.orderID = o.OrderID 
Join Customers c2 on o.CustomerID = c2.CustomerID
Group by Country, CategoryName, year(o.OrderDate)
Having year(o.OrderDate) = 1997
ORDER BY 3, 1, 2  DESC
```

[image]

I want to show only the highest category for each country. Please Help!!!

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `row_number` analytical function in your original query as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select
  COUNTRY, 
  CategoryName, 
  SUM(od.unitprice * od.Quantity),
  Row_number() over (partition by country order by  SUM(od.unitprice * od.Quantity) desc) as rn
From Categories c 
Join Products p on c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID  
Join [Order Details] od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
Join Orders o on od.orderID = o.OrderID 
Join Customers c2 on o.CustomerID = c2.CustomerID
Group by Country, CategoryName, year(o.OrderDate)
Having year(o.OrderDate) = 1997)
Where rn = 1
ORDER BY 3, 1, 2  DESC
```

Comment: If it solved your issue then accept this answer so that your question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

After some deliberation, and trying most of the suggestions I found the answer by using row partition:

```
Select * from
    (Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COUNTRY ORDER BY SUM(od.unitprice * od.Quantity) DESC) AS 'ROW_NUMBER', country, categoryname, SUM(od.unitprice * od.Quantity) as Valor
    From Categories c 
    Join Products p on c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID  
    Join [Order Details] od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
    Join Orders o on od.orderID = o.OrderID 
    Join Customers c2 on o.CustomerID = c2.CustomerID
    Group by Country, CategoryName, year(o.OrderDate)
    Having year(o.OrderDate) = 1997) as tbl
    Where tbl.ROW_NUMBER = 1
```